# bindingRedirect keeps switching back

Tags: assembly-binding-redirect

In my web project I have a `<dependentAssembly>` element with a `<bindingRedirect>` element. The attributes of this are an `oldVersion` with a range and a `newVersion`.

I am changing the new version to be the same as the assembly I've added to my project references. When I rebuild the solution, it changes back to the original value.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it.

For those wanting specifics, the current element is:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.0.0" newVersion="15.1.0.0"/>
```

What I want it to be is:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.0.0" newVersion="2017.8.3.7"/>
```

According to this page, the `newVersion` value does not have to be within the range specified in `oldVersion`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing this message in the output window:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: IOService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Comparing two files: "C:\git\IOService\Source\IOService\web.config.Debug" with "C:\git\IOService\Source\IOService\web.config"
1>  Comparing files C:\GIT\IOSERVICE\SOURCE\IOSERVICE\Web.config.debug and C:\GIT\IOSERVICE\SOURCE\IOSERVICE\WEB.CONFIG
1>  ***** C:\GIT\IOSERVICE\SOURCE\IOSERVICE\Web.config.debug
1>  <?xml version="1.0"?>
1>  <configuration>
1>  ***** C:\GIT\IOSERVICE\SOURCE\IOSERVICE\WEB.CONFIG
1>  ´╗┐<?xml version="1.0"?>
1>  <configuration>
1>  *****
1>  
1>  Files are not the same.  Copying "C:\git\IOService\Source\IOService\web.config.Debug" over "C:\git\IOService\Source\IOService\web.config"
```

So it turns out that VS was actually overwriting my main web.config with the .debug version because it did not match.